# Html, CSS : Sidebar sub menu not appearing

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have been following a tutorial online about creating a sidebar and i have run into an issue. When i hover over one of the menus a sub menu appears. But if i put anything to the right of the menu the sub menu does not appear only when you put the mouse over it. I want the menu to appear over the text to the right of the sidebar

The menu works perfectly when nothing is to the left (e.g. overflow:auto;)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/827/) is a jfiddle example of the issue

**HTML**

```
    <nav id="sidebar-menu">

        <ul class="parent-sidebar-menu">

            <li><a href="#">Home & Kitchen</a>

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                </ul>

            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Electronics</a>

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                </ul></li>

            <li><a href="#">Clothing</a>

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                </ul></li>

            <li><a href="#">Cars & Motorbikes</a>

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                </ul>

            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Books</a>

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>

                </ul>

            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Support</a>

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">Deliveries</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">T&C</a></li>

                </ul>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </nav>

</div>

<div align="top">

    <p>this is just a test</p>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
p, ul, li, div, nav
        {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }


        body
        {
            font-family:Calibri;
        }


        #sidebar-menu {
            overflow: visible;
            position:relative;
            z-index:2;
        }


        .parent-sidebar-menu {
            background-color: #0c8fff;
            min-width:200px;
            float:left;
        }


        #sidebar-menu ul
        {
            list-style-type:none;
        }


        #sidebar-menu ul li a
        {

            padding:10px 15px;
            display:block;
            color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none;
        }


            #sidebar-menu ul li a:hover
            {
                background-color:#007ee9;
            }





#sidebar-menu ul li:hover > ul {

                left: 200px;

                -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

                -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

                -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

                transition: left 200ms ease-in;

            }


            #sidebar-menu ul li > ul {

                position: absolute;

                background-color: #333;

                top: 0;

                left: -200px;

                min-width: 200px;

                z-index: -1;

                height: 100%;

                -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

                -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

                -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

                transition: left 200ms ease-in;

            }


            #sidebar-menu ul li > ul li a:hover

            {

                background-color:#2e2e2e;

            }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sub-menu actually is showing up; it's just the background color that doesn't show up. Right now, you have the background color applied the sub-menu's UL. If you instead apply the background-color to the LIs within that UL, it fixes the issue (I think this might be because of the UL's very low z-index?).

Anyway, here's the CSS rule to add:

```
#sidebar-menu ul li > ul li {
    background-color: #333;
}
```

You can then remove the background-color from `#sidebar-menu ul li > ul` since it doesn't do anything.

Comment: thanks that did the trick :-) just a quick question, at the moment thsub menus are appearing from the top, do you know how to make the sub menu pop out to start from the option you have selected?

Comment: Hmm, been trying to play with making that happen. You're definitely gonna want to change `#sidebar-menu ul li > ul` to be `position: relative; top: -40px;`, but that causes your menu items to be way too tall, not sure how to fix...

Comment: ah just said id ask anyways, ill keep trying. you answered my main question anyways so thanks :-)

Comment: Actually I've got it. Do the CSS I mentioned in my previous comment, and then explicitly set `#sidebar-menu ul li { height: 40px; }`, and then you're golden! [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/829/)

Comment: Basic rundown of why this works. Setting the sub-menu UL tells it to be positioned relative to its parent (which is the LI in the main menu) will let it be lined up with its menu item. This causes it to render directly _below_ the A tag, so we set `top: -40px` to move it back up alongside the A tag. Using `position:relative` also causes the LI tag to include the sub-menu in the auto height, making it wayyyy too tall. So we force the LI tag to be 40px tall (technically the sub-menu is overflowing out of the LI). And haha, glad it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have a z-index of -1 (so behind everything) on the CSS for your rollover.
Changing the Z-index of the #sidebar-menu ul li > ul to 100 and the z-index of the #sidebar-menu to 200 fixes it.
This should be your CSS:

```
p, ul, li, div, nav
    {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }


    body
    {
        font-family:Calibri;
    }


    #sidebar-menu {
        overflow: visible;
        position:relative;
        z-index:200;
    }


    .parent-sidebar-menu {
        background-color: #0c8fff;
        min-width:200px;
        float:left;
    }


    #sidebar-menu ul
    {
        list-style-type:none;
    }


    #sidebar-menu ul li a
    {

        padding:10px 15px;
        display:block;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;
        z-index:100;
    }


        #sidebar-menu ul li a:hover
        {
            background-color:#007ee9;
        }





#sidebar-menu ul li:hover > ul {

            left: 200px;

            -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

            -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

            -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

            transition: left 200ms ease-in;

        }


        #sidebar-menu ul li > ul {

            position: absolute;

            background-color: #333;

            top: 0;

            left: -200px;

            min-width: 200px;

            z-index: 1;

            height: 100%;

            -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

            -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

            -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;

            transition: left 200ms ease-in;

        }


        #sidebar-menu ul li > ul li a:hover

        {

            background-color:#2e2e2e;

        }
```

Comment: This makes the submenu appear over the main menu when it transitions in, but otherwise it doesn't fix it; the background still isn't visible. [Here's a jsfiddle using this CSS.](http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/828/)